# How to create a collage from Image urls in Python

Tags: python, django, image-processing, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a list of image urls (.jpg). I need to create a collage of all these images and I am looking for a python library that can do it.

I have explored the following libraries in depth but with no results:

1) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collage/ - The best of the lot. Unfortunately, it takes a generic argument( for example, "The Avengers", "Mark Twain"), Google searches for images(need a token. Has limitations), and then outputs an Image collage. Will take a couple of days to fork the app into a library

2) https://github.com/fwenzel/collage - Creates an unattractive horizontal collage. Again need some forking

3) https://github.com/adrienverge/PhotoCollage - Application. No good.

Are there any libraries that directly take urls, download them and make a collage, or make a collage out of PIL image objects? I have checked out pretty much every library that Google search and SO has to show. I am desperately hoping there is some obscure library out there that can help my cause.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking for this, using just Python if possible. Ideally I want to go from a Pandas DataFrame of company names, company logo urls and a descriptor such as 'industry'. The function would group by industry and make a collage of company logos per industry. A good example image here: http://bit.ly/1I5zg7t

Answer (score 1):

There is a Django package for this, very similar to your first option but with Django integration:

[Django-Collage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-collage/1.0.1)

If you have a set of images in your template, you can use it's filter to renderize them with:

```
{% load collage %}
{% load cache %}

{% cache 31536000 images view.id %}
    {% get_collage for view.get_images as images %}
    <div>
      {% for image in images %}
        <a href="{{ image.src }}" style="{{ image.css }}">
          <img src="{{ image.url }}">
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endcache %}
```

This code is taken from the tutorial provided in the package. I recommend you to check the official tutorial to learn how to use it.

Comment: I checked out this one as well. I need to create a file. I think this library simply rearranges the images in 2-d space, but does not create the final collage file. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could use a view with this Django-Collage to "generate" the collages. Meaning you have a template to generate the collage, and little JQuery/Javascript to extract the generated collage and store it where you need it. Sorry because I don't know about other libraries, I just know this one!